# What object can prove the equations?

Tags: riddle

I'm trying to solve this riddle as a part of wherigo cache in Granada, but I'm stuck...

What is the only object that can prove that 6+9=3 and 7+11=6?

Comment: I don't know what "wherigo cache in Granada" means, but if your puzzle is part of an ongoing contest, then special rules apply for posting and answering.

Comment: it's not a contest, just geocaching, a hobby

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The object is

> A clock.

This is because

> 9 hours after 6am is 3pm, and 11 hours after 7am is 6pm.

Comment: @1shar1 Welcome to Puzzling! Please consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/310115) this answer if it solved the question.

Comment: @Lukas Rotter done